# Wrapper strange behavior

Tags: java, casting, wrapper

hi guys am kinda new to the language i made this simple program about Fibonacci
and the program works fine but there is strange behavior when i try to get the average number

```
public class fibonacci {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static int fibonaccifun(int number)

{
    int firstvar=1;
    int secondvar=0,total=0,sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
    {
        total =firstvar+secondvar;
        System.out.println(total);
        firstvar=secondvar;
        secondvar=total;
        sum+=total;

    }

return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



     float aver= (float) ( fibonacci.fibonaccifun(5)/5);
    System.out.println(aver);
```

....................................

when i try

`float aver= (float) ( fibonacci.fibonaccifun(5))/5;` the result is 2.4 which is the correct value ,however when i do this

`float aver= ((float) fibonacci.fibonaccifun(5)/5);`  the average =2.0;

i dont know why it do this  so can anyone helps me explaining this ,thx guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because in the second case

`fibonacci.fibonaccifun(5)/5`

goes to 2, as both the result of `fibonaccifun` and 5 are ints, **THEN** you cast to float. (If you divide 2 ints, the result is an int, and ints obviously can't have decimals)

In the first case

`(float) ( fibonacci.fibonaccifun(5))`

makes the result of `fibonaccifun` a float, **THEN** you do the division.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast at least numerator or denominator

```
((float) fibonacci.fibonaccifun(5)/5)
```

You are dividing 2 ints. You'll never get anything but an int casted to float (hence the 2.0)

Fix:

```
(((float) fibonacci.fibonaccifun(5))/5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Order of Operations: In mathematics and computer programming, the order of operations (sometimes called operator precedence) is a rule used to clarify unambiguously which procedures should be performed first in a given mathematical expression.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Parenthesis
Exponents
Multiplication
Division
Addition
Subtraction

This is a perfect example of how just a switch of parenthesis can throw an entire program's logic out the door.